# Inversion of differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

My goal is to solve the differential equation, written in the following form
$$\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+I\Big)^{2n}V(x)=x+C$$
where $C$ is some constanst.
I want to do it by the operator method. Namely one can see that

$$V(x)=\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+I\Big)^{-2n}x+\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+I\Big)^{-2n}C$$

The question arises here is how to find the $\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+I\Big)^{-2n}$?

Should I apply first $\Big(\frac{d}{dx}+I\Big)^{-1}=I+\frac{d}{dx}+...$, and then repeat this $2n-$times?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course try to apply the binomial series,
$$
(1+A)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{r}{k}A^k
$$
with $A=\frac d{dx}$ and $r=-2n$. Note that $\binom{-m}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{m+k-1}k=(-1)^k\binom{m+k-1}{m-1}$.

---

You can also transform $V(x)=e^{-x}U(x)$ with $$U'(x)=e^x\left(I+\frac d{dx}\right)V(x),\quad U^{(k)}(x)=e^x\left(I+\frac d{dx}\right)^kV(x).$$

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you very much